# How to set minimum width on a TextButton (without changing minimum height)

Tags: flutter

Lets say I have this `TextButton`:

```
TextButton(
   style: TextButton.styleFrom(
     minimumSize: const Size(newWidth, newHeight),
   ),
  onPressed: _onTapped,
  child: const Text('Button'),
),
```

### Is there a way to set the minimum width **while retaining whatever was the minimum height**?

The motivation here is to keep the theme's values and overriding only what I need.
I was hoping that `TextButton.defaultStyleOf(context)` would be helpful alas it is not a static method.

Some notes:
I am not looking to use the old material buttons like `FlatButton` as they are being replaced with the new buttons (`TextButton` in this case), which is why I have this question in the first place.
But if there is a way to achieve that with `MaterialButton`, that would be good enough.

Comment: have you solve this problem?

Comment: I would also like to know how to set the "minWidth: double.infinity" <-- that works with FlatButton but not TextButton why?

Answer (score 5):

Use MediaQuery for size in ratio.

TextButton(onPressed:()
{

```
            },
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Colors.white,
              backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
              onSurface: Colors.grey,
              minimumSize: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-20,40)
            ),
            child: Text("Button")),
```

by default it take width according to its text width Or you can try with MediaQuery